# How to use commercial themes with meteor.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor

I'm a newbie who's trying to build a meteor app, and I was looking to cut some time by using a commercial theme. Let's take this as an example:

http://themeforest.net/item/metronic-responsive-admin-dashboard-template/4021469?WT.ac=category_item&WT.seg_1=category_item&WT.z_author=keenthemes

I have two options:

1) Use the html to create meteor templates, using spacebars tags, etc. 
But how would I implement the theme javascript? doesnt it comes in conflict with meteor?

2) Use angular.js, as the theme is provided in angular.js format other than plain html. But wouldnt this create conflicts? is this a better approach?

In general, what is the easiest and best way to use commercial themes with meteor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I bought similar themes on wrapbootstrap. I think it is the same problem here. (for Angular theme I do not know, as it would be trickier I think to integrate it with bootstrap)

Generally with such themes, you have a lot of 3rd-part JS libraries. You have to get them.
First option, you find a similar packages on atmosphere and you can add it. (A lot of jQuery library are simply wrapped as packages).

Second option, there is no such package (you can make and add them, and it would help the community :)). You can import them on the page you need with a package like [wait-on-lib](https://atmospherejs.com/manuelschoebel/wait-on-lib)

You can import the libraries where you need them only. But I think the first option is cleaner.

And you will probably have some custom.js for each different page you have in your template, you have to transfer this logic when you render a template. For example the custom.js for the index file in your template will be transformed in :

A template name index where you can put the HTML and

```
Template.index.rendered = function(){
/* your custom js */
}
```

For the CSS you can simply copy past the files in client/css (for example) the files will be loaded.

I do not know if I have been very clear, but I managed to integrate such themes in meteor project. And do not forget to remove unnecessary files, for example when you add the bootstrap package, you can remove the bootstrap css and js files integreted to your template.

P.S : You may have to search/remplace path in the css and js files from the templates to load some images for example. Put all such files (as images) in your public folder, where you want, but do not forget to rewrite the path in your css and js files.
For example if you bougth a template where they have folder like :

```
folder_css
folder_image
...
```

the path are written this way :

```
/* css files */
background-image: url(../folder_image/myimage.png);
```

But in a meteor project, all files in public folder are at the root of the project, so you can rewrite your path, with for example something like this :

```
/* css files */
background-image: url(img/myimage.png);
```

Rewrite path in JS files also and I think it should work.